# Showing "Error: Syntax error. Missing ')' " in formula expression

Tags: formula-field

```
IF((Currency_Type__c == 'INR')&&NOT(Type__c == 'Permanent Placement')&&(Rate_Pattern__c == 'Hourly'),
        IF( Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c >0, Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c *180, 0 )-Current_CTC__c/12 , 

    IF((Currency_Type__c == 'USD')&&NOT((Type__c == 'Permanent Placement'))&&((Rate_Pattern__c == 'Hourly')), 
        IF( Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c >0, Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c *180*60, 0 )-Current_CTC__c/12 , 

    IF((Currency_Type__c == 'EURO')&&NOT((Type__c == 'Permanent Placement'))&&((Rate_Pattern__c == 'Hourly')), 
        IF( Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c >0, Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c *180*80, 0 )-Current_CTC__c/12 ,

IF((Currency_Type__c == 'INR')&&NOT((Type__c == 'Permanent Placement'))&&((Rate_Pattern__c == 'Daily')), 
        IF( Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c >0, Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c *20, 0 )-Current_CTC__c/12 ,
IF((Currency_Type__c == 'USD')&&NOT((Type__c == 'Permanent Placement'))&&((Rate_Pattern__c == 'Daily')), 
        IF( Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c >0, Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c *20*60, 0 )-Current_CTC__c/12 ,
IF((Currency_Type__c == 'INR')&&NOT((Type__c == 'Permanent Placement'))&&((Rate_Pattern__c == 'Daily')), 
        IF( Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c >0, Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c *20*80, 0 )-Current_CTC__c/12 ,





IF((Currency_Type__c == 'INR')&&(Type__c == 'Permanent Placement')&&(Rate_Pattern__c == 'Permanent'),Current_CTC__c*Percentage_For_Margin__c/100 , 

IF((Currency_Type__c == 'USD')&&(Type__c == 'Permanent Placement')&&(Rate_Pattern__c == 'Permanent'),Current_CTC__c*Percentage_For_Margin__c*60/100 , 

IF((Currency_Type__c == 'EURO')&&(Type__c == 'Permanent Placement')&&(Rate_Pattern__c == 'Permanent'),Current_CTC__c*Percentage_For_Margin__c*80/100, 






IF((Currency_Type__c == 'INR')&&NOT((Type__c == 'Permanent Placement'))&&(Rate_Pattern__c == 'Monthly'),Revised_rate_by_client_INR_p_m__c-Current_CTC__c/12 , 

IF((Currency_Type__c == 'USD')&&NOT((Type__c == 'Permanent Placement'))&&(Rate_Pattern__c == 'Monthly'),(Revised_rate_by_client_INR_p_m__c-Current_CTC__c/12 )*60 , 

IF((Currency_Type__c == 'EURO')&&NOT((Type__c == 'Permanent Placement'))&&(Rate_Pattern__c == 'Monthly'),(Revised_rate_by_client_INR_p_m__c-Current_CTC__c/12 )*80, 

IF( Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c >0, Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c *80, 0 )-Current_CTC__c/12 
))))))))))
```

Comment: Kind of obvious isn't it that you have a `+` at the very end of what you've posted.

Comment: sry about the + sign its not in the code. please check now

Answer (score 2):

From the error it is clear that you are missing the bracket. I have add two bracket in the end and it will save. check that

```
IF((Currency_Type__c == 'INR')&&NOT(Type__c == 'Permanent Placement')&&(Rate_Pattern__c == 'Hourly'),
        IF( Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c >0, Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c *180, 0 )-Current_CTC__c/12 , 

    IF((Currency_Type__c == 'USD')&&NOT((Type__c == 'Permanent Placement'))&&((Rate_Pattern__c == 'Hourly')), 
        IF( Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c >0, Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c *180*60, 0 )-Current_CTC__c/12 , 

    IF((Currency_Type__c == 'EURO')&&NOT((Type__c == 'Permanent Placement'))&&((Rate_Pattern__c == 'Hourly')), 
        IF( Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c >0, Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c *180*80, 0 )-Current_CTC__c/12 ,

IF((Currency_Type__c == 'INR')&&NOT((Type__c == 'Permanent Placement'))&&((Rate_Pattern__c == 'Daily')), 
        IF( Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c >0, Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c *20, 0 )-Current_CTC__c/12 ,
IF((Currency_Type__c == 'USD')&&NOT((Type__c == 'Permanent Placement'))&&((Rate_Pattern__c == 'Daily')), 
        IF( Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c >0, Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c *20*60, 0 )-Current_CTC__c/12 ,
IF((Currency_Type__c == 'INR')&&NOT((Type__c == 'Permanent Placement'))&&((Rate_Pattern__c == 'Daily')), 
        IF( Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c >0, Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c *20*80, 0 )-Current_CTC__c/12 ,





IF((Currency_Type__c == 'INR')&&(Type__c == 'Permanent Placement')&&(Rate_Pattern__c == 'Permanent'),Current_CTC__c*Percentage_For_Margin__c/100 , 

IF((Currency_Type__c == 'USD')&&(Type__c == 'Permanent Placement')&&(Rate_Pattern__c == 'Permanent'),Current_CTC__c*Percentage_For_Margin__c*60/100 , 

IF((Currency_Type__c == 'EURO')&&(Type__c == 'Permanent Placement')&&(Rate_Pattern__c == 'Permanent'),Current_CTC__c*Percentage_For_Margin__c*80/100, 






IF((Currency_Type__c == 'INR')&&NOT((Type__c == 'Permanent Placement'))&&(Rate_Pattern__c == 'Monthly'),Revised_rate_by_client_INR_p_m__c-Current_CTC__c/12 , 

IF((Currency_Type__c == 'USD')&&NOT((Type__c == 'Permanent Placement'))&&(Rate_Pattern__c == 'Monthly'),(Revised_rate_by_client_INR_p_m__c-Current_CTC__c/12 )*60 , 

IF((Currency_Type__c == 'EURO')&&NOT((Type__c == 'Permanent Placement'))&&(Rate_Pattern__c == 'Monthly'),(Revised_rate_by_client_INR_p_m__c-Current_CTC__c/12 )*80, 

IF( Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c >0, Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c *80, 0 )-Current_CTC__c/12 
))))))))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

You were missing two parens at the end of your formula and also had some extra ones inside your formula which I removed.

```
IF((Currency_Type__c == 'INR')&& NOT(Type__c == 'Permanent Placement')&&(Rate_Pattern__c == 'Hourly'),
IF( Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c >0, Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c *180, 0 )-Current_CTC__c/12 , 

IF((Currency_Type__c == 'USD')&& NOT(Type__c == 'Permanent Placement')&&(Rate_Pattern__c == 'Hourly'), 
IF( Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c >0, Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c *180*60, 0 )-Current_CTC__c/12 , 

IF((Currency_Type__c == 'EURO')&& NOT((Type__c == 'Permanent Placement'))&&(Rate_Pattern__c == 'Hourly'), 
IF( Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c >0, Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c *180*80, 0 )-Current_CTC__c/12 ,

IF((Currency_Type__c == 'INR')&& NOT(Type__c == 'Permanent Placement')&&(Rate_Pattern__c == 'Daily'), 
IF( Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c >0, Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c *20, 0 )-Current_CTC__c/12 ,
IF((Currency_Type__c == 'USD')&& NOT(Type__c == 'Permanent Placement')&&(Rate_Pattern__c == 'Daily'), 
IF( Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c >0, Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c *20*60, 0 )-Current_CTC__c/12 ,
IF((Currency_Type__c == 'INR')&& NOT(Type__c == 'Permanent Placement')&&(Rate_Pattern__c == 'Daily'), 
IF( Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c >0, Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c *20*80, 0 )-Current_CTC__c/12 ,

IF((Currency_Type__c == 'INR')&&(Type__c == 'Permanent Placement')&&(Rate_Pattern__c == 'Permanent'),Current_CTC__c*Percentage_For_Margin__c/100 , 

IF((Currency_Type__c == 'USD')&&(Type__c == 'Permanent Placement')&&(Rate_Pattern__c == 'Permanent'),Current_CTC__c*Percentage_For_Margin__c*60/100 , 

IF((Currency_Type__c == 'EURO')&&(Type__c == 'Permanent Placement')&&(Rate_Pattern__c == 'Permanent'),Current_CTC__c*Percentage_For_Margin__c*80/100, 


IF((Currency_Type__c == 'INR')&& NOT(Type__c == 'Permanent Placement')&&(Rate_Pattern__c == 'Monthly'),Revised_rate_by_client_INR_p_m__c-Current_CTC__c/12 , 

IF((Currency_Type__c == 'USD')&& NOT(Type__c == 'Permanent Placement')&&(Rate_Pattern__c == 'Monthly'),(Revised_rate_by_client_INR_p_m__c-Current_CTC__c/12 )*60 , 

IF((Currency_Type__c == 'EURO')&& NOT(Type__c == 'Permanent Placement')&&(Rate_Pattern__c == 'Monthly'),(Revised_rate_by_client_INR_p_m__c-Current_CTC__c/12 )*80, 

IF( Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c >0, Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c *80, 0 )-Current_CTC__c/12 
))))))))))))
```